# Run node Docker without port mapping

Tags: node.js, docker

I am very to new Docker so please pardon me if this this is a very silly question. Googling hasn't really produced anything I am looking for. I have a very simple Dockerfile which looks like the following

```
FROM node:9.6.1
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm start
EXPOSE 8000
```

In the container the app is running on port 8000. Is it possible to access port 8000 without the `-p 8000:8000`? I just want to be able to do

```
docker run imageName
```

and access the app on my browser on localhost:8000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740344/how-to-publish-ports-in-docker-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish ports in docker files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740344/how-to-publish-ports-in-docker-files)

Comment: The answer is no. The docker file is to build the image and you use CMD [ "npm", "start" ] in the dockerfile to tell it exact what to run when the images starts up. Using docker is to sandbox the image. So you need to tell docker what you want to expose, network type to set , files to mount to disc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the  ‍‍`--publish` or `-p` flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host.
Read more: [Container networking - Published ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)

But you can use `docker-compose` to set config and run your docker images easily.

- First installing the `docker-compose`. [Install Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose)
- Second create `docker-compose.yml` beside the `Dockerfile` and copy this code on them

  ```
  version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
       - "8000:8000"
  ```
- Now you can start your docker with this command
  `docker-compose up` 
  If you want to run your services in the background, you can pass the ‍‍`-d` flag (for “detached” mode) to `docker-compose up -d` and use `docker-compose ps to see what is currently running.

[Docker Compose Tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but someone might find it useful:

1. First get the IP of the docker container by running

   docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
2. Then connect to it from the the browser or using curl using the IP and port exposed :

Note that you will not be able to access the container on 0.0.0.0 because port is not mapped