# Plain .NET 5 project runs in Docker but doesn't reacts to requests

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a plain .NET 5 project with the default weather forecast. Running locally, it behaves as expected and the call to *http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast* gives me the data. However, trying to reach the same address when running in Docker container fails. The only difference I can see between the logs is that they listen to different ports. The setup follows roughly [the docs on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows).

Locally it is 5000/5001.

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

Containerized it is 80.

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: http://[::]:80

That surprises me because I published those two ports as shown in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#connect-using-network-port-mapping). In the Docker desktop client, I can see *port: 5000* mentioned (but not 5001). I tried to access Swagger on port 80 with little success (I removed `env.IsDevelopment()` to make sure that both dev and prod work the same way). I tried both *create/start* and *run*. Same result. According to [this blog](https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/docker-expose-port/), publishing a port, exposes it too, so no additional `expose` in the Dockerfile is needed (although I've tested that too).

```
docker create --publish 5000:5000 --publish 5001:5001 --name dotnet5 dotnet-core-5:webapi
```

What can I be missing?

The whole *Dockerfile* looks like this.

> from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
> copy bin/Release/net5.0/publish /app
> workdir /app
> entrypoint ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]

Comment: If the application within the container runs on port `80`, and we want to make it accessible on port `5000` on the host, we need a `--publish 5000:80`. I cannot comment on why the port is different between local execution and container exceution since I am not familiar with .net applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It listens on port 80 in the container because Microsoft set the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable in their aspnet Docker images to `http://+:80` which overrides your configuration.

To get it to listen on something else, you have to set the ASPNETCORE_URLS variable yourself in your Dockerfile.

To get it to listen on port 5000 and 5001 like you want, you need to add

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000;https://+:5001
```

to your Dockerfile

They set it in the `runtime-deps` image, which is the base for the `runtime` image, which is the base for the `aspnet` image. You can see it here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/d8dc00685a45b7f534e9f68ded50667023ded151/src/runtime-deps/3.1/bullseye-slim/amd64/Dockerfile

Comment: I can't get it to work, yet. I noticed that checking the logs, still states `Now listening on: http://[::]:80` in the Docker window. I have amended your suggestion as the last line in my Dockerfile so it should be ran after the entry point is set. Another thing I wonder - wouldn't it be better to let it stay unaletered at post 80 (in the container) and simply expose it to port 80 in my local browser to make it appear, somehow?

Comment: Or perhaps I'm complicating needlessly? Can I just disregard whatever is the the *laynchsettings.json* of my project and simply reuse the default setting on port 80 both in the container and in my local browser? For some reason, when I go `--publish 80:80`, I get 404... And in the logs I get *Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware* - *Failed to determine the https port for redirect.*

Comment: If you've added the `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000;https://+:5001` line to the Dockerfile but it still listens on port 80, I'm thinking that maybe you've added it in the build section of the file. It needs to be in a part that ends up in the final image.
You can also let it listen on port 80, but then you need to remove the code that redirects to https in your program. Usually that's a call to `UseHttpsRedirection` in Program.cs or Startup.cs.

Comment: Perhaps it's my ignorance of the Dockerfile structure. I have no "sections" as such. Simply `from-copy-workdir-entrypoint`. That's all. I've made it work using non-secure protocol now but it would seem to me like compromise on my effort to stop now. Please do tell - should I make my Dockerfile partitioned somehow? I've read the linked MSDN article but didn't notice anything specific in this regard.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear about that. You probably have 2 or more 'FROM' statements in your Dockerfile. By 'section' I mean a FROM statement and the statements after it, until the next FROM statement. Only the things after the last FROM statement in your Dockerfile ends up in the image. So if you place the `ENV` statement in my answer after the last FROM statement, it'll end up in the image and it should work.

Comment: You have way too high thoughts of my Dockerfile, hehe. It's only got a single *from*. I'll give it one more try tomorrow to see what I did wrong. But it's literally 4 lines (plus fifth as you specified with *env*, which I put after the *entrypoint*). I'll post the whole shabang in the question. Perhaps I'm missing something due to incompetency.

Comment: A though I had (instead of serving on another port, which I seem to do wrong) - is it possible to publish so that port 80 (in container) maps to port 5000 (in browser) **but from the Dockerfile**? I have only found [exposing on but not publishing to](https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/docker-expose-port/) a port. Does it even makes sense to set the mapping of port in container to a port in browser before starting the container?

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, that's not possible with plain Docker. But you can use `docker-compose` to run the container and define what ports, volumes etc. should be used.

Comment: Ah, yes. Once I got the keywords properly in my googling (which I initially failed to due to incorrect taxonomy on my part), I've found [precisely what you just said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32740738/1525840). And with a clear motivation how dumb my question actually was. I get happy when I'm corrected. That's when I learn. :)